# Setting text from array in React Native thru props

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native but I'm sure that with the course that I'm following, the official docs, and you guys, I can make something awesome!

My question:
I have a screen which I use to render 2 lines of text on the screen. Those lines of text are randomly being chosen from an array. So far it all works as how it should. 
I'm passing the text that has been chosen thru props to the view. This works aswell but here is the problem that I have.
Once someone presses on the screen, I want the text to change to the next object of the array.

This is my code now:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { QUESTION } from '../data/all-questions'
import QuestionView from '../components/questionView';

const game = () => {
    const questionArray = [];
    const questions = QUESTION;
    var questionNumber = 0

    function getRandomIndex(items) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var removedItem = questions.splice(getRandomIndex(questions), 1);
        questionArray.push(...removedItem)
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { questionNumber = questionNumber + 1 }} >
            <QuestionView
                title={questionArray[questionNumber].title}
                question={questionArray[questionNumber].question}
                color={questionArray[questionNumber].backgroundColor}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default Game;
```

This is the Question class:

```
class Questions {
    constructor(id, title, question, backgroundColor, mode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.question = question;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.mode = mode;
    }
}
export default Questions;
```

How can I achieve the thing I've written above.
Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself, if you have comments on how I did it, please let me know!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { QUESTION as questions } from '../data/all-questions'
import QuestionView from '../components/questionView';


const Game = ({ questionsArray = questionsArray }) => {// Pass a prop to the component

    var questionsArray = [];
    // Here's a helper function that will pull a random iterable item from the passed `items` array
    const selectItemFrom = items => ({ ...items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)] });

    // We can still use a for loop to build up the array; there might be a better way.
    // Doing it out of the scope of the game component will set it up once, rather than every time
    // the component is rendered.
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        questionsArray.push(selectItemFrom(questions));
    }


    const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState(0);
    const { title, question, backgroundColor } = questionsArray[questionNumber]; // Destructure the single question

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1)}>
            <QuestionView title={title} question={question} color={backgroundColor} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

export default Game;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close; you just need to use React to manage your state.

In your import statements:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// Explanation: we need the useState hook provided by React
```

In your variable definitions:

```js
const [questionNumber, setCurrentQ] = useState(0);
// Explanation: Here we're using useState to initialize questionNumber to 0, as 
// well as give ourselves a function to adjust the value of questionNumber
```

And in your JSX:

```js
// Explanation: use the function we got from the useState hook to change the
// value of questionNumber
return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCurrentQ(questionNumber + 1)}>
```

Here's a stab at moving the array of questions out of the scope of the component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { QUESTION as questions } from '../data/all-questions'
import QuestionView from '../components/questionView';

const questionsArray = [];

// Here's a helper function that will pull a random iterable item from the passed `items` array
const selectItemFrom = items => ({ ...items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)] });

// We can still use a for loop to build up the array; there might be a better way.
// Doing it out of the scope of the game component will set it up once, rather than every time
// the component is rendered.
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  questionsArray.push(selectItemFrom(questions));
}

const Game = ({ questionsArray = questionsArray }) => { // Pass a prop to the component
  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState(0);
  const { title, question, backgroundColor } = questionsArray[questionNumber]; // Destructure the single question

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1)}>
      <QuestionView title={title} question={question} color={backgroundColor} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I get the following error: TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'questionArray[questionNumber].title')


When I change this part of the code: 
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var removedItem = questions.splice(getRandomIndex(questions), 50);
        questionArray.push(...removedItem)
        console.log(questionArray)
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCurrentQ(questionNumber + 1)}>


I can press more times, but it still won't work as how it should.

Comment: Are you actually populating your questionArray with question objects?

Comment: Yes, if I console.log my array, it shows a filled Array

Comment: Is it successfully switching from one question to the next? If so, at some point you'll need to check to see if you've come to the end of the `questionArray` and you don't have another question to show.

Comment: It is switching from one to another. But it crashes randomly. Like if I start it, it crashes the first time, if I restart it than it crashes the 4th time, than the 2nd time and so on. No logic.

Comment: Well, there could be a number of things going on there.  My suggestion would be to separate the creation of the array of questions from the component itself; right now, you build a fresh array every time the component is rendered.  Then you can inspect the data better and see what's going on there.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, however...
I'm kinda new, can help help with starting, than I'll try to get it done my self ;)

Comment: Thanks, I think we are almost there. Only problem now is that the array is not being filled. I'll try to fix this myself, but if you want, feel free to post the answer :) .

The exact error is: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I have edited my question and added the question class